# ReportViewer 15 using in IE11 Browser Not Supported error

Tags: visual-studio-2015, internet-explorer-11, reportviewer

I have a VS2015 C# web application that uses the ReportViewer2015 control to view SSRS 2016 reports.  All is good when using Edge, Chrome, and FF.  However many users are still using IE11, and when this happens I get a "Browser Not Supported" error.

I've tried adding the meta tags for Edge and Chrome as recommended by others l and I get the same error.  I've tried replacing edge with ie11 in the meta tag with no luck either.  I also have !DOCTYPE html in the the page as well...I've seen some recommendations for this.  In VS2015 in the toolbar, the target schema for validation dropdown is set to DOCTYPE:XHTML5...I'm not sure if this contributing to my issues with ie11?

I really can't ask users to modify their IE11 browser to address this issue, so I hope I'm just missing something I can manage on my side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your code whether you have add the following meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

It might be a [common error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/integrating-reporting-services-using-reportviewer-controls-get-started?view=sql-server-2017).

If still not working, can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Besides, here is an article about how to [use the Report Viewer Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/integrating-reporting-services-using-reportviewer-controls-get-started?view=sql-server-2017), you could refer to it.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Yes I've tried adding the meta tag you mention, no luck. The article that you've included is worth a try.  I'll see if that leads me to anything I've overlooked...

Comment: The reportviewer lives on a webform that is inside of a frame of another webform.  Once I added the meta tag you mention above to the "parent" webform IE11 started working.  After walking through your last link it made me realize this was my issue...thanks for the help!